# How can I configure IPython 0.12 to log all input to log-files split out by timestamp? I have this working in IPython 0.10.1

Tags: python, logging, ipython

Here's the relevant part of my `~/.ipython/ipy_user_conf.py` file on a system running IPython .10.1:

```
import IPython.ipapi
ip = IPython.ipapi.get()

import os
from time import strftime

def main():

    try:
        basedir = '/home/stu/.ipython/log/'
        logdir = strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        directory = os.path.join(basedir, logdir)

        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.mkdir(directory)

        logfilename = strftime("%s") + ".log"
        filename = os.path.join(directory, logfilename)

        ip.IP.logger.logstart(logfname=filename, logmode='append')

    except RuntimeError:
        print "something went wrong!"

main()
```

This logs all input during interactive sessions to files of the form: `/home/stu/.ipython/log/2012-04-26/1335454387.log`

How can I configure IPython 0.12 to create logs in this manner?

Is it ideal to create a `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/00-logstuff.py` file for this?

Does anyone have a set of `~.ipython/<profile>/startup/` scripts which could serve as good practical examples?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this recipe. You can modify it to do folder-per-day rather than file-per-day easily enough.

http://wiki.ipython.org/Cookbook/DatedLog